# Autocorrelation in linear mixed models (lme)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, random-effects-model, acf-pacf

To study the diving behaviour of whales, I have a dataframe where each row corresponds to a dive (id) carried out by a tagged individual (whale).
For each dive I calculate a series of parameters (maximum depth, duration, etc.).

```
# Example dataframe
id whale max_depths duration pd_times    d_rate     a_rate    bottom_dur  bottom_prop dive_type  diel   
1   1         57      166       41      0.5288462  0.9152542          2     1.2048193         F  Day
2   1         26      165       43      0.2688172  0.3333333          2     1.2121212        NF  Day
3   1         18      140       90      0.1911765  0.3500000         31    22.1428571        NF  Day
```

There are two type of dives ( F in which the whale feeds and NF where there is no feeding activity)

I want to compare all parameters between F and NF dives.

For that, I started by trying to apply a linear mixed model for each parameter with whale number as random effect and diel (since their behaviour may change according to time of day) as fixed effect (code below):

Diel -> in this column it is specified at what time of day the dive was carried out (for example, in one day if the sunrise is at 6:00h and sunset at 20:00h:

- from 6:00 - 19:00h = "Day"
- from 19:00 - 20:00h = "Twilight" (in this case "Dusk")
- from 20:00h till the begin of "Dawn" of the next day is "Night" and this continues based on local sunrise/sunset values

So if a dive was carried out at 18:00h of that day, in diel it would be "Day" and if the next dive was carried out at 19:15h it would be in the "Night" category.

```
    model_3 <- lme(duration ~ dive_type + diel_1, random=~1 | whale,method = "REML",
                   data = data,na.action=na.exclude)
    summary(model_3)
    AIC(model_3) 
    plot(model_3) 

> summary(model_1)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  33143.93 33167.49 -16567.96

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | whale
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    92.03755 116.9184

Fixed effects: duration ~ dive_type 
                Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 291.57762 20.491341 2653  14.22931       0
dive_typeNF -61.55134  4.656191 2653 -13.21925       0
 Correlation: 
            (Intr)
dive_typeNF -0.123

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-3.2584814 -0.7034402 -0.1069537  0.5686564  5.4987687 

Number of Observations: 2675
Number of Groups: 21
```

When I plotted the residuals I found they were not normal and there was a high level of autocorrelation (graph below)

[image]

After tranforming the data (log) the distribution seems closer to normal but there is still a high autocorrelation.

To try to fix these issue I included the corAR1 function as follow:

```
model_6_cor_2 <- lme(duration ~ dive_type  + diel_1, random=~1 | whale,method = "REML",
                   data = data,
                   #correlation=corARMA(p=2,q=0),
                   correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | whale),
                   na.action=na.exclude)
summary(model_6_cor_2)
AIC(model_6_cor_2)
```

But the autocorrelation plot remains basically the same.

[image]

I tried a GLM with Poisson and negative binomial distribution and the problem remains.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the time/lag variable here ? I know in your other question you mentioned that you could not include time in the corAR1 function because of repeated diel values - please can you edit the question and explain this a bit more ? If the measurements are repeated at different times of the day, you might need to specify the interection between day and diel, but I'm not sure I am understanding the design properly yet.

Comment: Hello Robert, I added an explanation of diel as asked. Thanks!

Comment: Agree with Robert. If you have repeated measures at different time points, you need to model the interaction between time and type of dive. From the information available is not clear if you have enough data to model time as a continuous variable or it's better discretising it.

Comment: OK thanks, I understand what diel is now, but isn't there another time variable for the actual date/day ? What was the syntax of the model which included time for which you got the error ? Were you just specifying  `corAR1(form = ~ diel | whale)` ? That definitely won't work. Instead you need something like  `corAR1(form = ~ diel:day | whale)`

Comment: Another question :)  Only `dive_type` and  `diel_1` are included in your model, but you have several other variables that vary with each dive. Some of the autocorrelation (and `whale` & residual variance) may be accounted byt those those variables. Is there any reason why you haven't included them ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try to include the interaction. Regarding the actual date/day I haven't included that variable. My data is quite spread in terms of date/year (1 or 2 whales per year where tagged) so I don't think I can use season or year as factor (not representative enough of each season/year).

Comment: Regarding the other variables, my goal was to see what varibles varyed according to dive type (including the influence of diel because previous research stated that the whales dive behaviour is differs between night and day). Is it a wrong approach to model each metric separately?

Comment: Meanwhile I tried using corARMA and it solved the problem of autocorrelation!

Comment: It looks as if you have used the default residuals where you need the normalized residuals to include the effect of the covariance structure; do `resid(model, type = "normalized")` to access the required residuals

Comment: I'm not sure this is appropriate, but could you calculate first difference to see if the autocorrelation is removed? You would lose one observation per whale.

Answer (score 1):

Gavin Simpson raised a good point in the comment that there are several types of residuals to plot: regular, standardized, and normalized. You want to use the normalized one to plot if you want to examine how much of autocorrelation is resolved by a first-order auto-regression process, such as `plot(ACF(model, maxLag = 78, resType = "normalized"), alpha = 0.05)`.

Usually either random effects or autocorrelation should be modeled by the same grouping indicator but not both. If you already have a random intercept varying by whale, it already captures the correlation between multiple measurements taken from the same whale, so it will be redundant to use autocorrelation. In fact, you will probably see that either the random-effect standard deviation is zero or the autocorrelation coefficient is at boundaries, if you keep both terms in the model. Use `intervals` to check if at least one of them cannot be accurately estimated. You can compare whether random effects or autocorrelation is a better choice by using `anova()` or AIC.

But before you start to worry about autocorrelation, make sure that you sort the observations in the correct order, as `lme()` by default use the implicit row index as the time indicator. See other modeling procedures in my answer [Is it possible to calculate x-intercept from a mixed model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612270). In your case, dive duration and depth are both positive integers, you can model them as (1) count model, perhaps zero truncated (2) survival analysis, such as Cox proportional hazard model (3) gamma regression (4) ordinal regression. With the predictors, it is possible and perhaps very useful to include season as categorical and year as numeric predictors, then you may discover astonishing findings such as "whales do dive as deep as they used to, possibly due to food scarcity, vessel disturbance, and marine pollution."