# GLS Function - Fitting and Interpretation Issues

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, model, generalized-least-squares

I am well aware, that this is a FAQ, but other questions could not provide me answers to my question. Also, I hope this will not be considered a double post, since I have posted this issue with a different question ([see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636649/how-to-perform-mixed-effect-model-for-data-with-repeated-measurements)).

I have data that I fit into a `gls` model from the `nlme` package in R. This is what the data looks like

```
fid|Treatment|NDVI_mean|date      |Management1
1          G 0.7918969 2018-10-11     Control
2          J 0.1899928 2018-10-11    Clearcut
3          H 0.2378630 2018-10-11    Clearcut
4          C 0.3631807 2018-10-11       PR1/2
5          D 0.3294372 2018-10-11       PR1/2
6          E 0.4611494 2018-10-11       PR3/4
7          F 0.3681659 2018-10-11       PR3/4
8          I 0.3020894 2018-10-11    Clearcut
9          B 0.3247002 2018-10-11          NR
10         K 0.3109387 2018-10-11          NR
11         L 0.8071204 2018-10-11     Control
12         G 0.8191044 2018-11-28     Control
13         J 0.1952865 2018-11-28    Clearcut
14         H 0.2209233 2018-11-28    Clearcut
15         C 0.3942993 2018-11-28       PR1/2
16         D 0.3285107 2018-11-28       PR1/2
17         E 0.4192142 2018-11-28       PR3/4
18         F 0.3856550 2018-11-28       PR3/4
19         I 0.2522038 2018-11-28    Clearcut
20         B 0.3300189 2018-11-28          NR
21         K 0.2990551 2018-11-28          NR
22         L 0.8361506 2018-11-28     Control
23         G 0.8274411 2018-12-05     Control
...
479         E 0.5348337 2022-06-15       PR3/4
480         F 0.4959483 2022-06-15       PR3/4
481         I 0.5295775 2022-06-15    Clearcut
482         B 0.4168112 2022-06-15          NR
483         K 0.4540260 2022-06-15          NR
484         L 0.6940871 2022-06-15     Control
```

The data recorded a NDVI (vegetation index i.e. greenness/vigor) time series over the span of four years. The `Treatment` are different study sites and `Mangement1` different treatments. Here is a plot for a better understanding:

[image]

I want to find out, how `Management1` is influencing the `NDVI_mean` values over time. Therefore, I have fit the data in a `gls` model:

`gls_model <- gls(NDVI_mean ~ Management1 + date, correlation = corCAR1(form = ~date | Treatment), data = Data_2018_2022)`

```
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: NDVI_mean ~ Management1 + date 
  Data: Data_2018_2022 
        AIC       BIC  logLik
  -1337.034 -1303.677 676.517

Correlation Structure: Continuous AR(1)
 Formula: ~date | Treatment 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Phi 
0.9850594 

Coefficients:
                         Value  Std.Error    t-value p-value
(Intercept)         -1.7199592 0.28986021  -5.933754       0
Management1NR       -0.4107973 0.02250663 -18.252277       0
Management1PR1/2    -0.4161073 0.02250663 -18.488207       0
Management1PR3/4    -0.3806264 0.02250663 -16.911743       0
Management1Clearcut -0.4365251 0.02054565 -21.246592       0
date                 0.0001345 0.00001567   8.588285       0

 Correlation: 
                    (Intr) Mng1NR M1PR1/ M1PR3/ Mngm1C
Management1NR       -0.039                            
Management1PR1/2    -0.039  0.500                     
Management1PR3/4    -0.039  0.500  0.500              
Management1Clearcut -0.043  0.548  0.548  0.548       
date                -0.998  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000

Standardized residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.7290950 -0.7069599 -0.1141165  0.6488433  3.2727331 

Residual standard error: 0.07468751 
Degrees of freedom: 484 total; 478 residual
```

I find that the estimates look somewhat unreasonable looking at the plots of my data.
If I fit the model in the following way: `gls_model <- gls(NDVI_mean ~ Management1 + fid, correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ date | Treatment), data = Data_2018_2022)`
The `summary()` seems to be more accurate for what I understand:

```
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: NDVI_mean ~ Management1 + fid 
  Data: Data_2018_2022 
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -1322.891 -1289.534 669.4456

Correlation Structure: Continuous AR(1)
 Formula: ~date | Treatment 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Phi 
0.9870169 

Coefficients:
                         Value   Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)          0.6889661 0.021376286  32.23039       0
Management1NR       -0.4110561 0.025436529 -16.16007       0
Management1PR1/2    -0.4148831 0.025436178 -16.31075       0
Management1PR3/4    -0.3794014 0.025436108 -14.91586       0
Management1Clearcut -0.4346909 0.023219982 -18.72055       0
fid                  0.0002791 0.000042286   6.60065       0

 Correlation: 
                    (Intr) Mng1NR M1PR1/ M1PR3/ Mngm1C
Management1NR       -0.592                            
Management1PR1/2    -0.596  0.500                     
Management1PR3/4    -0.595  0.500  0.500              
Management1Clearcut -0.653  0.548  0.548  0.548       
fid                 -0.540 -0.006  0.002 -0.001  0.003

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.80656156 -0.80840445 -0.07411791  0.62982805  3.34187612 

Residual standard error: 0.0794082 
Degrees of freedom: 484 total; 478 residual
```

Also, if I fit the model `gls_model <- gls(NDVI_mean ~ Management1, correlation = corCAR1(form = ~date | Treatment), data = Data_2018_2022)`, the output of the `summary()` seem to be valid, however, the standardized residuals vs. fitted values plot has a pattern.

**Question 1**: Do I interpret the output of the second model correctly by saying, that the `(Intercept)` value is the mean value of the `NDVI_mean` in `Management1Control` when `Management1` was equal to 0 and e.g. `Management1NR` would be equal to the `Intercept` minus `-0.4227368` ?

**Question 2**: How is it possible, that the model seems to produce a (from my understanding) valid output only if I include the `fid` in the model ?

**EDIT**
I followed the suggestion of @EdM and fitted the model `gls_model <- gls(NDVI_mean ~ Management1 * date, correlation = corCAR1(form = ~date | Treatment), data = Data_2018_2022)` 
The `summary()` now is

```
eneralized least squares fit by REML
  Model: NDVI_mean ~ Management1 * date 
  Data: Data_2018_2022 
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -1289.247 -1239.312 656.6233

Correlation Structure: Continuous AR(1)
 Formula: ~date | Treatment 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Phi 
0.9801462 

Coefficients:
                             Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)               0.598611 0.5475773  1.093199  0.2749
Management1NR            -2.691958 0.7743913 -3.476225  0.0006
Management1PR1/2         -2.344346 0.7743913 -3.027341  0.0026
Management1PR3/4         -2.427570 0.7743913 -3.134811  0.0018
Management1Clearcut      -4.913910 0.7069193 -6.951162  0.0000
date                      0.000009 0.0000296  0.306608  0.7593
Management1NR:date        0.000123 0.0000419  2.944852  0.0034
Management1PR1/2:date     0.000104 0.0000419  2.488846  0.0132
Management1PR3/4:date     0.000111 0.0000419  2.640983  0.0085
Management1Clearcut:date  0.000242 0.0000383  6.331952  0.0000

 Correlation: 
                         (Intr) Mng1NR Mn1PR1/2 Mn1PR3/4 Mngm1C date   Mn1NR: M1PR1/2: M1PR3/4:
Management1NR            -0.707                                                                
Management1PR1/2         -0.707  0.500                                                         
Management1PR3/4         -0.707  0.500  0.500                                                  
Management1Clearcut      -0.775  0.548  0.548    0.548                                         
date                     -1.000  0.707  0.707    0.707    0.774                                
Management1NR:date        0.707 -1.000 -0.500   -0.500   -0.548 -0.707                         
Management1PR1/2:date     0.707 -0.500 -1.000   -0.500   -0.548 -0.707  0.500                  
Management1PR3/4:date     0.707 -0.500 -0.500   -1.000   -0.548 -0.707  0.500  0.500           
Management1Clearcut:date  0.774 -0.548 -0.548   -0.548   -1.000 -0.775  0.548  0.548    0.548  

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.44410198 -0.65724392 -0.07158163  0.69272402  2.54105053 

Residual standard error: 0.06669597 
Degrees of freedom: 484 total; 474 residual
```

Comment: None of these models is valid. None includes the most important repeated measure here, the multiple measurements within each level of the `Treatment` variable. `Treatment`, not `date`, should be after the "|" symbol in your formulas. To handle autocorrelations over time, you _might_ include something like `~ date|Treatment`, with `date` kept as a fixed predictor. For the best ways to formulate`gls` models, see Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long).

Comment: Thank you very much @EdM. I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: The additive term for `date` doesn't allow for the slope with respect to `date` to differ among `Management1` values, yet the plots show very different slopes. You need a `Management1*date` interaction term for that. The `fid` numbers are just arbitrary indices of the order of measurements and shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion. That makes a lot of sense. However, the result seems not to be valid, if I am interpreting correctly (as I tried to decsribe above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final model

```
gls(NDVI_mean ~ Management1 * date, correlation = corCAR1(form = ~date | Treatment), data = Data_2018_2022)
```

seems to be OK and to do a reasonable job of fitting your data, although it only allows for linear changes in outcome over time.

The coefficient values seem weird because of how R encodes your `date` values. It uses the "number of days since 1970-01-01." Thus your earliest `date` of `2018-10-11` is already at a date value of `17185`. The `(Intercept)` and the individual coefficients for the `Management1` levels, however, are the estimates at `date = 0`, an extrapolation to times that are long before your study.

That said, if you use the model to get estimates corresponding to your actual dates, all seems pretty much OK.

For example, the `Control` values are reasonably constant over time, at a value of about 0.76. The low coefficient for `date` (representing the slope specifically for `Control`) is consistent with that. If you start with an `(Intercept)` of about 0.60 (the estimated value for `Control` at `date = 0`) and add in a slope of 0.000009 over the `17185` days since then, you get

```
0.60 + 17815*0.000009
## [1] 0.760335
```

That reconstructed the `Control` starting value OK.

The interaction coefficients between `date` and each of the other levels of `Management1` represent the *differences* from `Control` in slope. Consistent with your plots, each of those interaction terms is positive, with the apparent order in the slopes of your plots consistent with the coefficient values.

The single coefficients for each of the `Management1`levels also seem to be OK, once you take into account all the coefficients involved. I checked this in particular for the `NR` level. To get the estimate for `NR` at the start of your study, you need to start with the `(Intercept)` (`0.60`), add in the coefficient for `NR` (`-2.69`, the difference between `NR` and `Control` at `date = 0`), and the estimated linear change over the intervening `17815` days (`17815` times the sum of the `date` and `Management1NR:date` coefficients):

```
0.60 -2.69 + 17815*(0.000009 + 0.000123)
## [1] 0.26158
```

That agrees quite well with the starting value for `NR` in your plot.

The increase in that value for `NR` over the 1343 days of your study would be:

```
1343 * (0.000009 + 0.000123)
## [1] 0.177276
```

again agreeing well with your data.

The reason that you thought that you might have had a useful model when your used the `fid` values as a predictor and omitted `date` as a fixed predictor is that the `fid` values are very highly correlated with the `date` values, in the particular way that you set up your data. When using some arbitrary set of predictor values seemingly unrelated to what you thought you were studying seems to "work," take that as a sign that you need to re-evaluate what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time for this incredible explanation. I have added a variable with days passed to make things easier, and now everything makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.